# What is the difference between Swing and Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I have searched a lot on Google and I know that already this question is asked here but I am unable to find perfect answer what is the difference between applet and Swing and in which kind of application I should use applet or Swing?

Comment: An `Applet` is from the `java.awt` API, Swing is an entire GUI framework built on top of the `java.awt` API which provides a greater range of UI components and customisation...you can't really compare them

Comment: refer your textbook or any tutorial you will get a lots of differences.

Comment: *"I know that already this question is asked here.."*  Where? Link to it.

Answer (score 2):

Swing and applet actually overlap.

Swing is a GUI toolkit like AWT or Java-FX.

Both Swing and AWT offer applet containers.  The AWT one is `java.applet.Applet` and the Swing one is `javax.swing.JApplet`.

Comment: As an aside, a person with such basic confusion is not a person I would expect can make a workable applet.  They are more for experts that already comprehensively understand the GUI tool-kit they are using.